# Sprite animation error

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

My animation for a 37*37 resolution sprite is working swell a part from when I have both the left and right arrow key pressed down, two animations appear on top of each other.
Here is my code:

```
    keys = Keyboard.GetState();
        if (keys.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
        {
            position = new Vector2(position.X + 1.4f, position.Y);
            isRight = true;
            isLeft = false;
            if (keys.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
            {
                isLeft = true;
                isRight = false;
            }
        }
        if (keys.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
        {
            position = new Vector2(position.X - 1.4f, position.Y);
            isLeft = true;
            isRight = false;
            if (keys.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
            {
                isRight = true;
                isLeft = false;
            }
        }

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }



    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        spriteBatch.Begin();
        int frame = (int)((gameTime.TotalGameTime.TotalSeconds * 12) % 4);

        if (keys.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
            spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, new Rectangle(frame * 37, 0, 37, 37), Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 1.0f);
        if (keys.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
            spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, new Rectangle(frame * 37, 0, 37, 37), Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.FlipHorizontally, 1.0f);

        if (keys.IsKeyUp(Keys.Left) && keys.IsKeyUp(Keys.Right))
        {
            if (isRight)
                spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, new Rectangle(0, 0, 37, 37), Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 1.0f);
            if (isLeft)
                spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, new Rectangle(0, 0, 37, 37), Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.FlipHorizontally, 1.0f);
        }
        spriteBatch.End();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: draw method should only have draw elements, those iskeydown should be handled in update method. so on draw you pass only pure data.

Answer (score 0):

You have two animations appearing on top of each other because you have two separate `SpriteBatch.Draw` calls in your `Draw` method. When you press both left and right keys, both of `IsKeyDown` ifs are true, and both draws are executed.

Also, this post is more appropriate in https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Alright, thanks. This is my first time posting on the website.